# Signed char literal for -1

Tags: c++17

I want to assign a special value (all bits set) to an int8_t variable. However, I'm getting
`enumeration value is outside the range of its underlying type ("signed char")`.

int8_t value = 0b11111111;

So how should I set the all bits set value? Should I move to uint8_t?

Comment: The notation for -1 is literally `-1`. `0b11111111` is not a notation for -1, it is a notation for 255. 255 is outside of the range of `int8_t`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply assign -1 or use `~0` and accept the implicit cast from `int`:

```
int8_t value = -1 ;
```

or

```
int8_t value = ~0 ;
```

Equally you can make it explicit:

```
int8_t value = static_cast<int8_t>(-1) ;
```

or

```
int8_t value = static_cast<int8_t>(~0) ;
```

Which may be required if you are applying a static analysis tool.

You could of course apply the cast to your binary initialiser, but the advantage of the above is that it works for any integer type regardless of width without the need to count bits in the initialiser.